# Connection lifetime and prepared statements in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a long-running windows service that constantly receives data and processes it, then puts it into the database.  I use stored procedures for the complex operations, but some of them have many parameters.

I'm aware that this is the suggested 'best practice':

```
using(IDbConnection connection = GetConnection())
{
   connection.Open();
   // Do stuff
   connection.Close();
}
```

Resulting in short-lived connections, but taking full advantage of connection pooling.  However, this practice really seems to negate the benefits of a stored procedure.  I have something like this at the moment:

```
while(true) 
{ 
  var items = GetData(); // network I/O
  using(IDbConnection conn = GetConn()) 
  {
    connection.Open();
    var tran = connection.BeginTransaction();
    var preparedStatement1 = SQL.Prepare(connection, "...", ...);
    var preparedStatement2 = SQL.Prepare(connection, "...", ...);
    var preparedStatement3 = SQL.Prepare(connection, "...", ...);

    foreach(var item in items) 
    {
      // loop which calls SQL statements.
    }
    connection.Close();
  }
}
```

I really feel that I should open the connection outside of the while loop so it stays alive a long time; and prepare the statements before entering the loop.  That would give me the full benefit of using the stored procedures:

```
using(IDbConnection conn = GetConn()) 
{
  connection.Open();
  var tran = connection.BeginTransaction();
  var preparedStatement1 = SQL.Prepare(connection, "...", ...);
  var preparedStatement2 = SQL.Prepare(connection, "...", ...);
  var preparedStatement3 = SQL.Prepare(connection, "...", ...);

  while(!service.IsStopped) 
  { 
    var items = GetData(); // network I/O  
    foreach(var item in items) 
    {
      // loop which calls SQL statements.
    }      
  }
  connection.Close();
}
```

So the question is, does the performance benefit of stored procedures outweigh the "risks" of leaving connections open for a long time?  The best practices never seem to mention prepared statements, and the MSDN documentation (I'm using SQL Server) seems to suggest `Prepare()`ing will sometimes be a no-op: [`SQLCommand.Prepare()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx)

Comment: A connection can stay open if it's used anyway. So there's nothing wrong in it. You just need to ensure that it gets closed as soon as it's unused.

Comment: You're probably going to find that against SQL Server, the call to `Prepare` is going to be negligible, as the query plans are cached (depending on use).  That said, have you *tried* and measured the difference?  That's the easiest way to tell.